# Duplication issue on fetching calendar provider events

Tags: android, android-calendar

Same events are getting repeated When I fetch event list from Calendar Provider.Moreover, i could see the same issue in default calendar app (Not google calendar app).But the event is shown only once in google calendar app.I debugged the code and I could find that each of the repeated events has its unique event id, so I cannot filter them.

I am using this code snippet to fetch event of a day

```
       Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = 
       CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
       ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MIN_VALUE);
       ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                eventsUri,
                new String[]{CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID, 
                CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE,
                CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION, 
                CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN,
                CalendarContract.Instances.END, 
                CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
                CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY, 
                CalendarContract.Instances.START_DAY, 
                CalendarContract.Instances.END_DAY, 
                CalendarContract.Instances.START_MINUTE},
                "((" + CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " >= " + 
                Long.toString(startTime.getTimeInMillis()) + " AND " + 
                CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN
                        + " <= " + 
                (Long.toString(endTime.getTimeInMillis())) + ") OR "

                        + "(" + CalendarContract.Instances.END + " >= " + 
       Long.toString(startTime.getTimeInMillis()) + " AND " + CalendarContract.Instances.END
                        + " <= " + (Long.toString(endTime.getTimeInMillis())) + ") OR "
                        + "(" + CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " <= " + Long.toString(startTime.getTimeInMillis()) + " AND " + CalendarContract.Instances.END
                        + " >= " + (Long.toString(endTime.getTimeInMillis())) + ")) "

                        + " AND " + CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 1"
                        + " AND calendar_id != " + getCalendarId(context),
                null,
                CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " ASC");
```